# predict a type of car and connect the results to IDs

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm building a predictive model for whether a car is sport car or not. The model works fine, however I would like to join the predicted values back to the unique IDs and visualize the proportion, etc. Basically I have two dataframes:

1. Testing with labelled data - test_cars

| CarId | Feature1 | Feature2 | IsSportCar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | 150 | True |
| 2 | 60 | 200 | False |
| 3 | 560 | 500 | True |

2. Unlabelled data to be predicted - cars_new

| CarId | Feature1 | Feature2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 88 | 666 |
| 5 | 55 | 458 |
| 6 | 150 | 125 |

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

# Create arrays for the features and the response variable
y = test_cars['IsSportCar'].values
X = test_cars.drop(['IsSportCar','CarId'], axis=1).values

X_new = cars_new.drop(['CarId'], axis=1).values

# Create a k-NN classifier with 10 neighbors
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)

# Fit the classifier to the data
knn.fit(X,y)

y_pred = knn.predict(X_new)
```

The model works fine, but I would like to join the predicted values back to each car (CarId), so the car_new dataframe would be outputted with predicted column "IsSportCar":

| CarId | Feature1 | Feature2 | IsSportCar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 88 | 666 | False |
| 5 | 55 | 458 | True |
| 6 | 150 | 125 | True |

Any ideas how to join the predicted values back to the unique IDs?

Comment: What about use `pd.concat`?

Comment: *"join the predicted values back to each car (CarId)"* is a very roundabout way of simply saying *"create a new column in my dataframe 'IsSportCar' with the predicted value for each row/CarId in the test-set"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cars_new['IsSportCar'] = y_pred
```

I assume `y_pred` is the variable you want to put into `cars_new`?